# Ruby: How to get array instead of DataMapper::Collection in query result

Tags: ruby, arrays, collections, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

here is my code:

`today_ids_from_db = Rating.all(:fields => 'my_id', :ts_d => Time.now)`

`today_ids_from_db.class == DataMapper::Collection`

but I need to get simple ruby array with my_id values

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Rating.all(:ts_d => Time.now).map(&:my_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try out this **Activerecord** beauty called [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)

```
Rating.where(:ts_d => Time.now).pluck(:my_id)
```

Comment: I like that better, but it still should be pointed out that this is Rails 3.2.* only.

Comment: @dimitkocheckout this  http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2?view=asciicast which talks about pluck method at 3:08 seconds in Rails 3.2.0